# Text based not working Adventure Game href not working php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a Text-based Adventure Game but when you press either one of the buttons on the website it redirects as an error, I dont know why this is

https://icsprogramming.ca/2020-2021/luu4e5ab/activity-2-3c.php/

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Text-based Adventure Game</title>    
    
    <meta name="description" content="Text-based Adventure Game using PHP">
    <meta name="author" content="kl">   
    
    <!-- styles - internal (not linked) -->
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            background-color: #ececec; 
            color: #333333;
            font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>CYOA Text-based Game: Simple</h1>
    <p>Choose wisely!</p>
    
<?php
    $option = $_GET['option'];
    
    if ($option == "") {
        echo "<p>You are standing in a dark room with 2 doors.  One to the left and one to the right.  You must make a choice.
        <br /><a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php?option=1'>LEFT DOOR</a> | <a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php?option=2'>RIGHT DOOR</a>
        </p>";
    } else if ($option == "1") {
        echo "<p>You chose the left door.  Very wise.  The door shuts behind you and locks.  You are standing in another room.  There are two tunnels leading out of the room.<br />
        <a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php?option=3'>LEFT TUNNEL</a> | <a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php?option=4'>RIGHT TUNNEL</a>
        </p>";
    } else if ($option == "2") {
        echo "<p>You have parished. Sorry.<br /><a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php'>START AGAIN</a></p>";
    } else if ($option == "3") {
        echo "<p>You have parished. Sorry.<br /><a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php'>START AGAIN</a></p>";
    } else if ($option == "4") {
        echo "<p>You have parished. Sorry.<br /><a href='text-based-cyoa-example.php'>START AGAIN</a></p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>You have made an invalid selection!</p>";                
            }
?>
    
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you've you've just got your HREF in the link tags wrong... Browsing around a little, it looks there is no `text-based-cyoa-example.php` file

I think you want to be navigating to:
`https://icsprogramming.ca/2020-2021/luu4e5ab/activity-2-3c.php/?option=1`

Or preferably keeping things relative, so you can use something like:

```
<a href="/?option=1">Left Door</a><a href="/?option=2">Right Door</a>
```